# Ebay custom listing header

Tags: javascript, html, ebay-api

I've been working on an ebay store with a custom header and I am using javascript to modify the existing header, so my final product should look something like this: http://stores.ebay.com/coastnationalsales
I've compleated this task, but now my client wants the store to appear under each item like this one: http://www.ebay.com/itm/iLuv-iEP322-City-Lights-Explosive-Bass-In-Earphones-Headphones-/330863436337
I've been researching several similar ebay shops and all of them have an iframe, containing the shop. There are 2 possible sollutions: to create such a system, that will keep each listed item in our own database and addit as a description using iframe, or to use an existing one. I've checked several ebay shops and all of them have the same iframe source:

- http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=370762312858&t=0&tid=10&category=40177&seller=us_micro&excSoj=1&rptdesc=1&excTrk=1&tto=3500&lsite=0
- http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=330872380297&t=0&tid=10&category=10976&seller=pompeii3&excSoj=1&rptdesc=1&excTrk=1&tto=3500&lsite=0
- http://vi.sandbox.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&sd=1&item=110109067274&bv=safari&t=1352025083000&vct=1&nv=2&js=-1&ssid=0&category=98624&ds=0&seller=testuser_kjo&caz.html
- http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=370760386229&t=1355740747000&tid=310&category=57920&seller=rococlothing&excSoj=1&rptdesc=1&excTrk=1&tto=3500&lsite=3
- [...]

This tells me, that all of them are clients of the same company, that created such listing system or it's some kind of a default ebay functionality, that I cannot find.

How can I create such store listing header? I am open to any ideas - html + iframe, javascript, ...

Thank you in advance.

**P.S.** When I include the header in the listed item it includes the default header and not my custom one, so the javascript modifications that I made are not included by default...

Comment: Hi, I have exactly same requirement as you had but I'm not getting the way how to modify iframe under item description page. You marked the answer but I am wondering how you did it.
It will big help if you show the way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the shop header into the listing and you can deactivate the default shop header in the ebay account settings.